# crontab automated git pull

Tags: python, git, cron, git-pull

I have a server deployed. I am writing a crontab task. It uses a python script that need to check if there is new push into the repository. If it finds a new push, it will pull and update the server code and should restart the server.

My problem is how to make the python script know if there is new commit into the repository?

I know you can use

```
git rev-list deployment..origin/deployment
```

to check if there is any commit is available on the remote server.

But how to implement in the python script and make it decide to know that it need to pull?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Why not `fetch` and conditionally merge and restart if there is something to merge?

Comment: Are you using github by chance?  Something like service hooks is probably better than a cron.

https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

Comment: not github.. 
but how do u know when do u need to merge? this server will be in data center remotely..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to contact the server in any case, so you might as well pull.

If you are on the current branch when you pull, and want to detect whether the current branch has changed, you can always do (note: written in shell)

```
BEFORE=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
# git pull here
AFTER=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
# Changes if $BEFORE is different from $AFTER
```

Comment: what does git rev-parse HEAD do?

Comment: `git rev-parse <refspec>` prints the SHA1 for the given refspec. `HEAD` is the head of the current branch. A refspec can also be a local or remote branch etc.

Answer (score 1):

fge is correct. You cannot see if someone else pushed without first either doing a `git pull origin` or a `git fetch origin`.  Your command would have worked with a `git fetch origin` first.

```
git fetch origin
git rev-list deployment..origin/deployment
```